# Image stretch on page resize - css changed through jquery - needs a refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image-scaling

I have a large horizontal scroll who's height I am setting via javascript/jquery. It renders fine initially, and on resize I have it change

```
(if div.height > page.height ) div.height:100%;
```

Something of that nature, all working fine... and I have it switch back

```
(if page.height > specifiedheight ) div.height:specifiedheight;
```

Which works... but for some reason when it first renders the resize the images are all stretched horizontally... but if i continue the resize a bit more it fixes itself. Possibly a bug, I'm not sure. My width is always auto, and my height is either the specifiedheight or 100%. This could be a bug but i'm not sure. Perhaps there is a way to redraw the images or something so they won't stretch?

How to replicate this issue: http://elijahhoffman.com/test
size the page down below 550px high - you will see the value change. 
size it back up past 550px and let it go and you will see images strecth (depending on how far you sized it up)

The code i'm using:

```
function resizeevents() {
pageheight = $(window).height();
if (pageheight<scrollheight) {
 $('#hscroll').css('height','100%');
 $('#hscroll').css('margin-top','initial');
 $('#hscroll').css('top','initial');
}
else {
 $('#hscroll').css('height',scrollheight);
 $('#hscroll').css('margin-top',(-scrollheight/2));
 $('#hscroll').css('top','50%');
}

var resizeTimer;
$(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(resizeevents, 100);
});
```

scrollheight is specified in the initial document (in this case 550)

Comment: You need an `else` statement to reset the styles back.

Comment: The styles do set back this way, yes I suppose I should write it with an else statement but it would still render the same way I believe.

Comment: I would give the `else` statement a try but can this be achieved with `media queries`?

Comment: Yes it can, probably error free too - but I have different pages with different scrollheight's (image heights) and I'd prefer not to have to write a media query rule for every page.

Answer (score 0):

The timer was screwing everything up for some reason. I had it in there to save calculations, but it's not that big of a deal. everything is under the window.resize function now.